# Bootstrap container-fluid image not centered after max width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-images

I have an image (currently 1305 x 352 pixels) inside of a fluid-container like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="lion-div">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page width is at or smaller than the width of the image, the image scales to the full width of the page, which is what I want.

However, when the page width is larger, the image stays aligned to the left. I'd like it to stay in the middle of the page.

I've tried using margin-left and margin-right: auto on the div, even making a media container with min-width: 1306px and trying everything I know, but I can't get the image to center. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
.row-fluid{text-align:center;}
.img-responsive{margin:0 auto}
```

Comment: worked perfectly! didn't know text-align would work on the div. many thanks!